# ContextMenu is not displayed at correct position in scrollable div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jsp

There is a div inside an iframe. In that div, on right click i need to show context Menu.
Length of this div can be very long, resulting into a scrollable div.
Issue is, on right click, context Menu is appearing but not where the mouse is clicked. [image]

Comment: Is this on a website where you have access to all of the sourcecode, or are you making an addon (Extension)? And is the issue that you are having that the context menu won't appear at the same spot as the mouse-cursor is while right-clicking?

Comment: I am making my own project, and yes, the issue is context menu doesn't appear at the same spot as the mouse-cursor is while right-clicking. Actually length of my div is very long. and this div is like a tree with multiple leaves. so on rightclick on any of the leave (via scrolling) contecxMenu should be visible.

Comment: Thanks for the picture! A solution to this problem would be to dynamically set the css "position-attribute" of the context-menu via an eventlistener on the "add-buttons". Since by the looks of the the current context-menu is "stuck" to the top of your div.

Answer (score 0):

This pure js can get ahold of the mouse-position on right-click, and those coordinates can then be in the creation of the context menu. To make sure that the context-menu appears where the mouse is.

NOTE! This solution doesn't really utilise the "add-buttons" which you have shown.

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").addEventListener("contextmenu", setContextMenuPosition)

function setContextMenuPosition(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which === 3) {
        createContextMenu(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }
}

function createContextMenu(xCoord, yCoord) {
    let contextMenu = document.createElement("div");
    contextMenu.style.cssText = "position: fixed; top:" + xCoord + "; left: " + yCoord + ";";
}
```

Comment: Thats what I am doing in my current code. its not working. As context Menu appears on the parent screen not the child div. Hence its not appearing where the mouse is clicked.

Comment: @Gun any chance you could post your code? Would make alot of things easier.

Comment: Actually code is very complex, in multiple files. can't post it here.